# How to use date values in a spark-sql query?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**My Problem**

I'm trying to migrate a query that was written in SQL-server to spark SQL (Pyspark), but I'm experiencing issues with date comparisons. In SQL-server, my query runs fine and looks as follows:

```
DECLARE @hist_date date = '01-sep-2022';
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM dienstverband
    WHERE  DatumInDienst < @hist_date AND (DatumUitDienst >= @hist_date OR DatumUitDienst IS NULL)
) as dvb
```

**What I've tried**

But for obvious reasons, I cannot DECLARE in spark SQL queries, So I tried to do it as follows (this still works fine in SQL-server):

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \
    ( \
        SELECT * FROM bronze_SharedDatastore.dienstverband \
        WHERE  DatumInDienst < '01-sep-2022' AND (DatumUitDienst >= '01-sep-2022' OR DatumUitDienst IS NULL) \
    ) as dvb")
```

But I think that spark somehow doesn't understand that the string '01-sep-2022' is supposed to be a date object. So, I tried to explicitly cast the date string to a Date like so:

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \
    ( \
        SELECT * FROM bronze_SharedDatastore.dienstverband \
        WHERE  DatumInDienst < CAST('01-sep-2022' as date) AND (DatumUitDienst >= CAST('01-sep-2022' as date) OR DatumUitDienst IS NULL) \
    ) as dvb")
```

But this still doesn't work... Any ideas on how to pass a date into a spark.sql("sql_query_here") query? I know there probably exists some pyspark functions for this, but I need the SQL syntax because this query is a simplified version of reality. In reality my query is much more complex.

EDIT: I have verified that the columns I'm comparing on (DatumUitDienst and DatumInDienst) are in fact DateType() columns in pyspark.

Comment: The problem was that the DatumInDienst and DatumUitDienst columns had a DateType in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD. Changing my comparison to that format (So `2022-09-01` instead of `01-sep-2022`) solved the issue. I'd still love to learn why this *does* work in SQL server and *does not work* in spark, therefore I added this as comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Changing my comparison to that format (`'2022-09-01'` instead of `'01-sep-2022'`) solved the issue. I'd still love to learn why this does work in SQL server and does not work in spark.

The question really asks what formats are supported in date literals in SQL Server vs Spark.

TL/DR: SQL Server is excessively flexible in that regard, as opposed to most other databases, including Spark. Do use ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`, which is supported by most databases - or convert your input first.

---

**Spark**

Most databases follow the ISO convention where date literals are formatted like `YYYY-MM-DD`. Spark [takes that conservative root](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-literals.html#datetime-literal), along with a few variations (eg, `'2023'` would be interpreted as `'2023-01-01'`).

Typically, [Spark's built-in date functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#date-and-timestamp-functions) expect a string in this format. If you need to process a date string that has a different format, then you have to convert it using first, either using string functions or the `to_date()` built-in (that takes a format specifier as a second argument).

---

**SQL Server**

On the other hand, SQL Server accepts a *very wide* variety of representations, as you can [see in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-string-literal-formats-for-date), which may be numeric, alphabetical, ISO, and so on. This is very flexible, but might also lead to ambiguity (quick: what date does string `'02032023'` represent: March 2nd or Feb 3rd?). The documentation somehow recommends using the standard ISO format:

> The default string literal format, which is used for down-level clients, complies with the SQL standard form that is defined as YYYY-MM-DD. This format is the same as the ISO 8601 definition for DATE.